# Installing a GUI application in LXD/Docker with a GUI installer

Tags: lxc, docker, container

I have an old proprietary software which I need to run on newer distro. I hope containers are the solution.

The problem is that the old software installs itself from a GUI application which require interaction. All the apt based installation can be mentioned in the config file and will be dealt with during image creation.

How do I make a container so that when I start the container all these applications are pre installed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use "ssh -X" to SSH into the container and redirect X11 traffic back to your client. That may not be very fast but it should be good enough to go through the installer and get it going.

Alternatively you could use xpra and x11vnc to run the application attached to a fake X11 server and be able to see what's going on through VNC.